# Groovy MOP invokeMethod

Tags: groovy

I am trying to understand how invokeMethod intercepts method calls in Groovy. I can't seem to get the most basic of examples working though.

```
class Person implements GroovyInterceptable {

    def invokeMethod(String name,args) {
        println "called invokeMethod $name $args"
    }

    def greet() {
        println "Hello from greet()"
    }

}

def p = new Person()
p.greet()
```

If I try and run this example I get the following error. What am I missing?

```
Caught: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Person.invokeMethod(Person.groovy:4)
    at Person.invokeMethod(Person.groovy:4)
    at Person.invokeMethod(Person.groovy:4)
    ...
```

Comment: println is a method on Groovy object which was getting caught and therefore sending me into an infinite loop.

Using System.out.println which is not affected by our interception point fixed the issue. Thanks Venkat (Programming Groovy 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the actual method from `invokeMethod` after the interception.

```
class Person implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def invokeMethod(String name,args) {
        System.out.println "called invokeMethod $name $args"
        metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args).invoke(this, args)
    }

    def greet() {
        System.out.println "Hello from greet()"
    }
}

def p = new Person()
p.greet()
```

And yes you are correct about `println`. Have to use SOP.