# AOP for Groovy via closures and pattern matching?

Tags: java, regex, groovy, closures, aop

I have an abstract base POGO:

```
abstract class AuthorizingResource {
    void authorize(String credential) {
        if(!credentialIsValid(credential)) {
            throw new AuthorizationException(credential)
        }
    }

    boolean credentialIsValid(String credential) {
        // Do stuff to determine yea or nay
    }
}
```

And many concrete subclasses like so:

```
class FizzResource extends AuthorizingResource {
    List<Fizz> getAllFizzes(String credential) {
        authorize(credential)

        List<Fizz> fizzes

        // Do stuff

        fizzes
    }

    Fizz getFizzById(String credential, Long id) {
        authorize(credential)

        Fizz fizz

        // Do stuff

        fizz
    }

    void considerTheLillies(Buzz buzz) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    void upsertFizz(String credential, Fizz fizz) {
        authorize(credential)

        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

As you can see there's several things going on:

- Any `FizzResource` methods that I want authenticated/authorized, I need to manually call `authorize(...)` at the top of the method
- Some methods (`considerTheLillies`) do not need to be authed

I was wondering if I could mimic AOP by using a closure to call `authorize(...)` (so I don't have to keep adding it mindlessly) that can use some sort of pattern for selecting which methods to "wrap" inside the closure. In the particular case of the `FizzResource`, this would be any method that contains "`*Fizz*`" in it, but that pattern should be (ideally) any valid regex. **The one thing that can't change is that any method that accepts `credential` arg cannot have its signature modified.**

So basically, something like Spring AOP or Google Guice's method interceptors, but using native Groovy closures.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `invokeMethod` to intercept method calls and call `authorize` where applicable? Here is an example answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580008/groovy-mop-invokemethod/19591253#19591253

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `invokeMethod` with `GroovyInterceptable`. Note that any `fizz` in the name will be matched:

```
abstract class AuthorizingResource implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def invoked = []
    def validator = [credentialIsValid : { true }]

    void authorize(String credential) {
        if ( !validator.credentialIsValid(credential) ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(credential)
        }
    }

    def invokeMethod(String method, args) {
        if (method.toLowerCase().contains('fizz')) {
            metaClass.getMetaMethod('authorize', String).invoke(this, args[0])
            invoked.add( 'authorized ' + method )
        }
        return metaClass
            .getMetaMethod(method, args*.getClass() as Class[])
            .invoke(this, args)
    }
}

class Fizz { String name }

class FizzResource extends AuthorizingResource {
    List<Fizz> getAllFizzes(String credential) { ['all fizzes'] }
    Fizz getFizzById(String credential, Long id) { new Fizz(name: 'john doe') }
    def considerTheLillies() { 42  }
}

res = new FizzResource()
assert res.getAllFizzes('cred') == ['all fizzes']
assert res.considerTheLillies() == 42
assert res.getFizzById('cred', 10l).name == 'john doe'

assert res.invoked == ['authorized getAllFizzes', 'authorized getFizzById']
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't stop thinking about a closure based solution. I came up with some Javascript style code, using closures and maps. It features no inheritance:

```
class AuthorizingResource {
    void authorize(String credential) {
        if(!credentialIsValid(credential)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(credential)
        }
    }
    boolean credentialIsValid(String credential) { true }
}

class Fizz {}

abstract class FizzResource {
    abstract List<Fizz> getAllFizzes(String credential)
    abstract int getFizzById(String credential, Long id)
    abstract void considerTheLillies(buzz)

    static createFizzResource(authorized) {
        def auth = new AuthorizingResource()
        def authorize = { auth.authorize it; authorized << it }

        return [ 
            getAllFizzes       : { String credential -> ['fizz list'] },
            getFizzById        : { String credential, Long id -> 42 },
            considerTheLillies : { buzz -> }
        ]
        .collectEntries { entry ->
            entry.key.toLowerCase().contains('fizz') ? 
                [(entry.key) : { Object[] args -> 
                    authorize(args[0]); entry.value(*args) 
                }] : 
                entry
        } as FizzResource

    }
}
```

Testing:

```
def authorized = []

def fizz = FizzResource.createFizzResource(authorized)
assert authorized == []
assert fizz.getAllFizzes('getAllFizzes cred') == ['fizz list']

fizz.considerTheLillies null
assert authorized == ['getAllFizzes cred']

assert fizz.getFizzById('fizz by id cred', 90l) == 42
assert authorized == ['getAllFizzes cred', 'fizz by id cred']
```

Note the `authorized` list is very dumb, and only needed for `assert` purposes.